# Pullable view Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uiview, pull

I like to do a pullableview, to show a button, but not like notification center, its a custom button like this:
[image: First Stage]

And the second and final stage:

[image: Second Stage]

Anyone knows a library, contro to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a library for that? Just implement it yourself. Add a custom subview to your table view, or its superview. Add a swipe gesture recognizer to it, or implement the touch handler methods to respond to pulling by moving the view down. And finally add a button to it with a background image.

Comment: I really tried, but I'm having trouble adding the button to the subview, its a UITableViewController, and i already tried     [self.tableView.superview addSubview:qualquer]; or     [self.tableView addSubview:qualquer];

in the first case it not shows the button, and in the second case, it show, but in the position X=0 and Y=0, and i cant move it

Comment: Try using a UIViewController and add the UITableView and the custom view both to the view controller's view.

Comment: Still the same error, even if i put the button in the interface builder it doesnt show it